# Ajax and jquery redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, notifications

Hi there folks I have a jquery script to submit a form and if successful it sends json output back.

```
function subscribe(email, city){
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    var city = $('select#citySelect').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.amazingvouchercodes.co.uk/avc_dev/subscribe/subscribeTo',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'email='+email+'&city='+city,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            window.location.href = json['url'];
            $('#notifications').append('<div class="success">'+json['success']+'</div>');
        }
    }); 
}
```

the problem I have is that it is displaying the notification > json success before the redirect after redirect the notification doesnt show, is there a way to show the notification after the redirect?

Thanks all help is appreciated :)

Joe

Comment: What server-side framework are you using?  It sounds like a perfect use case for flash scope if your platform supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like AlienWebguy suggested,

It is because you are loading a new page, so any JavaScript gets reset.

I think the best way would be to have an element set in your layout/header that displays messages on the top of your screen (like how this site notifies you of something in the orange bar) if any are pending. So on your Ajax page, you set a notification (session/cookie) variable. Then the next time a page loads (after your redirect), the layout will know there is a notification pending, it displays it in the layout/header and clears it (so it only shows up once.)

Comment: I like the sound of this method, im quite new to jquery and jscript could u give me some info how to do this or point me to some reading material :)

Comment: @JoeElliott This is actually something that you would implement with a server side language (like PHP), not JavaScript. Like  wrschneider99 suggested in your comments, if you are using a server side framework (like CakePHP, RoR) most already have this built in.

Comment: i use codeigniter so is that session flash messages or something :)

Comment: I have never used CI, I am sure they have it, just not sure what its called. So you may just need to look at the docs. I have used CakePHP, which uses a method on the Session component called `setFlash` you pass it a message and it handles the rest (as long as your layout is setup to display flash messages.)

Comment: got it thanks for pointing me in  right direction sir :) have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like `window.location.href = json['url'] + "?redirMsg=Foo+Bar";` and on your pages check if `redirMsg` is in the query string, and if so, alert your notification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want the success function to cause a redirect, and then update something on the page you were redirected to?

If so, you will need to do it a little differently. The page you get redirected to will not continue executing the javascript that started executing on this first page.

One option is to append a querystring variable to tell the next page to update. Such as:

```
window.location.href = json['url'] + "?msg=success";
```

Then on the next page, it would check for that querystring variable, and do the update if it exists.

On the next page, you can include something like:

```
function getFromQuery(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}

if (getFromQuery("msg")=="success")
{
//do your update here
$('#notifications').append('<div class="success">'+json['success']+'</div>');
}
```